# Problem when adding C# as interesting tag

Tags: bug, status-declined

To reproduce:

From the questions-page: enter "C#" in the interesting tags field and press "Add".
C# now appears as a button just above the field. Press the button and you go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#
After you refresh the page, the button properly takes you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23

Seen on Firefox 3.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

duplicate; wont-fix as this is only a minor client-side issue on the initial add, and works fine on every subsequent page load.